# Error: fetching abi for eosio: unknown key

Tags: nodeos, transactions, api

I am trying to create and account from another account, both on JungleNet. I am using dffuse for my rpc. Here is my code:

```
const {Api, JsonRpc} = require('eosjs');
const {JsSignatureProvider} = require('eosjs/dist/eosjs-jssig');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const {TextDecoder, TextEncoder} = require('util');
const { PrivateKey } = require('eosjs-ecc');

const privateKey1 = '5Kh3sXKTY3ed4htCD5af69MiALyk44w3PdX18smX5hDV9Kx3AAh';

const privateKeys = [privateKey1];
const publicKey = PrivateKey.fromString(privateKey1).toPublic().toString();

const signatureProvider = new JsSignatureProvider(['5Kh3sXKTY3ed4htCD5af69MiALyk44w3PdX18smX5hDV9Kx3AAh']);
const rpc = new JsonRpc('https://jungle.eos.dfuse.io/', {fetch});
const api = new Api({rpc, signatureProvider, textDecoder: new TextDecoder(), textEncoder: new TextEncoder()});


(async () => {
    const res = await api.transact({
        expiration: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 30 * 60000),
        ref_block_num: 65981473,
        ref_block_prefix: 4183230361,
        actions: [{
            account: 'eosio',
            name: 'newaccount',
            authorization: [{
                actor: 'winterwind12',
                permission: 'active',
            }],
            data: {
                creator: 'winterwind12',
                name: 'winterwind14',
                owner:{
                    threshold: 1,
                    keys: [{
                        key: 'EOS5ZWJYNoFUYN62iQRc77LEdY2GfmRxLUgsbtWwMstJWbJwGMPHs',
                        weight: 1
                    }],
                    accounts: [],
                    waits: []
                },
                active: {
                    threshold: 1,
                    key: [{
                        keys: 'EOS5ZWJYNoFUYN62iQRc77LEdY2GfmRxLUgsbtWwMstJWbJwGMPHs',
                        weight: 1
                    }],
                    accounts: [],
                    waits: []
                },
            },
        },
        {
            account: 'eosio',
            name: 'buyrambytes',
            authorization: [{
                actor: 'winterwind12',
                permission: 'active',
            }],
            data: {
                payer: 'winterwind12',
                receiver: 'winterwind14',
                bytes: 8192
            },
        },
        {
            account: 'eosio',
            name: 'delegatebw',
            authorization: [{
                actor: 'winterwind12',
                permission: 'active',
            }],
            data: {
                from: 'winterwind12',
                receiver: 'winterwind14',
                stake_net_quantity: '0.5000 SYS',
                stake_cpu_quantity: '0.5000 SYS',
                transfer: false,
            }
        }]
    })
    // {broadcast: false, sign: true})
    // {blocksBehind: 3, expireSeconds: 30})

    console.log(res);
})();
```

After executing this, I get an error like this:

```
(node:18425) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: fetching abi for eosio: unknown key (eosio::chain::name): 
    at new RpcError (/home/hasnain/Projects/EOS/Test/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-rpcerror.js:26:28)
    at JsonRpc.<anonymous> (/home/hasnain/Projects/EOS/Test/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:118:35)
    at step (/home/hasnain/Projects/EOS/Test/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:36:23)
    at Object.next (/home/hasnain/Projects/EOS/Test/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:17:53)
    at fulfilled (/home/hasnain/Projects/EOS/Test/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonrpc.js:8:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:18425) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18425) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Where am I going wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

JsonRpc currently messes things up when being instantiated with an endpoint with a trailing forward slash, just use https://jungle.eos.dfuse.io instead of https://jungle.eos.dfuse.io/.

They fixed it in their `develop` branch (https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/develop/src/eosjs-jsonrpc.ts#L33), but it's not released yet.

Comment: If I do that, it gives me a different error:
https://gist.github.com/hali241997/d5b1af366bbd00197508e9500f971e7b